# With Maps 6.12 Latitude seems to have vanished?

Tags: google-maps, google-latitude

After updating, the Latitude widget seems to have vanished. And from Maps, I can't get to my Latitude friends anymore.

I can't find any notes about this online, in reports or on Google pages.

In the comments in the Play Store, others have mentioned this as well.

Is there a way to get this back, or is it running still in the background? Some sort of release note?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/maps/latitude/_6FrYJf57MI) with Google Maps for Android 6.10 the Latitude widget is no longer available. You can view your friends' locations quickly by touching the Latitude icon, or by turning on the Latitude layer in Google Maps.

Comment: Do you know if there is still a way to get a shortcut on my Home Screen to the Latitude screen of Maps?

Comment: Basically Latitude has been integrated into Google Maps, so there is no shortcut just to Latitude.  You have to access it through your Google Maps shortcut.

Comment: Too bad. I thought maybe they added something like in Gmail where you can create Shortcuts to different Labels.